# TCP Socket Implementation always gives old value

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Currently implementing a TCP socket in C. Using libcurl I am sending a HTTP POST request with some XML files. The connection and transmission is working correctly.

Now, when I try to send 2 different XML files in the same session to the server I always get the value of the first transmission I sent. Meaning I always get the old value, the socket does not give back the new value received on the socket.

Wireshark shows me that the different XML files are transmitted. Do I need to clean the socket somehow after each TCP connection has been made?

Here is my server implementation:

```
while (1) {
    char buf[512];

    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
    if (connfd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    int rec;
    rec = recv(connfd, buf, sizeof (buf), 0);
    printf ("Receive val: %d\n", rec);

    //DO STUFF

    //Send back ACK
    strcpy(sendBuff, "Received");
    write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));

    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: When you talk about "old value", are you talking about the contents of buf or the contents of rec?

Comment: I was referring to content of rec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you close the session right after the first packet is received. This is why you don't get the next packet.

You should handle each incoming connection in a separate thread, or make sure somehow before you close the socket, that no more incoming data should arrive

Comment: Yes it's supposed to be two separate connection, like from two different clients. Would I need to work with threads then to implement it in this way?

Comment: that's what's usually done. Each connection is handled in a separate thread.

Comment: actually if the data will be sent from two separate connections, then your problem wouldn't appear. and since you close the connection immediate after you get the information, you'll be able to work with several clients and wouldn't feel a big lag.
Still, threads are better as they allow real parallelism